# Send id as a permalink into database

Tags: php, permalinks

I want to send complete permalink into database like WordPress when we create a page a new permalink created with id like we create page

Home

it will generate permalink like this 
http://www.domain.com/project/?p=123

how to do this with custom php

Any help please

Comment: How could we help? Without seeing your **code**.

Comment: i didn't code it yet, i want to get the idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html

```
<form >
<input type="text" method="POST" name="permalink">
<input type="text" method="POST" name="name">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

php
save to db

```
$permalink = isset($_POST['permalink'])?$_POST['permalink'] : "";
$name = isset($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name'] : "";
$query = "INSERT INTO tablename SET name=".$name.", permalink=".$permalink ;
mysql_query($query);
```

load from db

```
http://www.domain.com/project/?p=someWord
$someWord = isset($_POST['someWord'])?$_POST['someWord'] : "";

$query = "select * from tablename where permalink=".$someWord;
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: so on the open link i can hardcode the url like this
<a href="www.domain.com/project/?p=$someword">www.domain.com/project/?p=$someword</a>

Comment: yes, you can hardcode or get the permanent words from DB and create urls by PHP code

Comment: thanx volkinc :)
I have a title of about us and set this title as a permailink like
<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/pages/template?title=<?php echo $url; ?>$url; ">About us</a>
and then url show me like this http://domain.com/pages/temlplate?title=about-us

so the question is there any other to do this or i can hide the title via htaccess. if there is any other solution then kindly share. thanx again...
but only one issue

Comment: Hi. two solutions. 1) create application that care for you about routing likw zend forman www.domain.com/controller/view/action but this require to build whole application the second one is htaccess

Comment: thanx volkinc i created this in codeignator all code working proplerly but with the htaccess its not working i have add the following code in htaccess. 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /domain.com/admin/index.php/pages/template?title=$1 [L]

Comment: RewriteRule ^urlcomponents/([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)desiredpermalink.html$ folderPathFromRoot/filename.php?param=$1 [QSA]

Comment: hey volkinc thanx man. you saved my lots of time. Every thing working perfect. just left 1 thing. how can i create diffrent template pages for diffrent page like wordpress. i want to create a template page of about-us. any idea.

Comment: welcome. question to you. if you doing something custom and want things like in a wordpress why you don't use wordpress on a first place? About templates. the simplest way to use - include "pathToTemplateFile.php"

Comment: <? //some logic here; include "header.php; include "bodytemplate.php"; include "footer.php" the mosyt interesting part is all vars from a logic at the begining of the file will be accessible in a body template.

Comment: sorry cant understand, can u describe in detail

Comment: Hi. Yes. What is a template it's a file with HTML and possibility to use php variables inside a template. the only method without using templaters like smarty or frameworks like wordpress and drupal etc is using INCLUDE command <? //some logic here; include "header.php; include "bodytemplate.php"; include "footer.php" ?> or you can use Smarty see the article http://www.broculos.net/2008/03/how-to-make-simple-html-template-engine.html#.U3yv1iifi7I